# Edit database directly with gridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

We're having problems with editing a database with a gridView. I've been looking around and I've seen that there are some options in the properties to put an edit link next to the gridView. 
 I've also seen the sqlDataSource Control, which seems to be a little too complicated for me.
 A user needs to be able to see the database content in the gridView, then be able to edit the content and clicking submit which updates the database with the changed content.

Is there any simple way to do this?
If not, any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's not working, you should provide your code so that we can help fix it. Otherwise, your question is too broad and there's plenty of ways to do this, but we're not a code writing service.